# Does @JoinTable has a property of "table" or not?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, join

The following is copied from hibernate's document. (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2770)

```
   @CollectionOfElements
    @JoinTable(
            table=@Table(name="BoyFavoriteNumbers"),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="BoyId")
    )
    @Column(name="favoriteNumber", nullable=false)
```

However, when I put this in practice, I just found that @JoinTable has no "table" property, instead it has a "name" property to specify the table name.  But I need "table" property to specify indexes.

What's going on here?  I'm almost driven crazy!

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't, this sample is not accurate. Just in case, the `@IndexColumn` annotation that you see in this sample has nothing to do with a database index, it is used to store the index number of an element in an indexed collection. But I guess you're aware of that.

Actually, I'd suggest to raise a Jira issue specifying your use case **and** your database dialect (it seemts that generating an index on the FK works with some dialects, like MySQL, but doesn't with say Oracle).

Comment: @Kent Agreed with you. I can think of two causes. 1. Maybe not so much people are really generating the physical model 2. Nobody never reported a complete issue with a testcase (like you should, also pointing out the problem in the doc).